# Servlet URL pattern to match a URL that ends with a slash ("/")

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml, url-pattern

**I'd like to specify a Servlet URL pattern to match a URL that ends with a slash ("/") and only a slash.**

I understand that the pattern

```
    /example/path/*
```

will match a URL of

```
    http://example.com/example/path/
```

and that this appears to work. However, that same pattern would also match URLs of

```
    http://example.com/example/path/a/
    http://example.com/example/path/b/
    http://example.com/example/path/c/
```

I'm merely looking for a URL pattern that will match `http://example.com/example/path/` only without also matching `http://example.com/example/path/a/` and so on.

Clarification: a URL pattern ending with a slash is not allowed.

Comment: Have you tried without the trailing star ? Eg
/example/

Comment: Yes, I've already tried this. NetBeans tells me a URL pattern ending with a slash is not allowed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's quite possible that you can't do this by mapping in web.xml.

What you can do is to map servlet to /mypath/* and then check part after /mypath/ via request.getPathInto(). If it is "/", run your code. If it isn't, return 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

In NetBeans, if I go to the Servlets tab on the web.xml file, the IDE would complain with, "Error: URL patterns cannot end with slash (/)". From the [URL spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), it reads,

```
httpurl        = "http://" hostport [ "/" hpath [ "?" search ]]
hpath          = hsegment *[ "/" hsegment ]
```

So yes, an URI with an ending slash is invalid.